# How are codeigniter's session system separated with PHP's built in $_SESSION?

Tags: codeigniter, session, php

As the manual says:

> Note: The Session class does not utilize native PHP sessions. It
>   generates its own session data, offering more flexibility for
>   developers.

But when I store some data using `$this->session->set_userdata(array('sample_key' => 'sample_value'));`, in `phpinfo()` I can find `sample_key` and `sample_value` in that.

I hoped that the part

> does not utilize native PHP sessions

to be meaning that it hides the session variables from `phpinfo()`.

I'd always thought that it might be a security lack. Could it be?

As it seems, the values are `urlencode`ed.

Comment: `phpinfo()` pages should not be publically accessible on a production system at all. I highly doubt anyone ever used session vars being shown in there as a reason to use a custom session system.

Comment: The true security issue would be having publicly available `phpinfo()` output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CodeIgniter's "session" just stores the data in a cookie, and calls it a session.  Native PHP sessions store the data on the server, and a "sessionID" in a cookie.

In `phpinfo`, you can see the variables, but it's *your* session, you can't see another user's session.

Comment: Very much false. There are a number of available session drivers, including one that stores data into the database.

Comment: @ceejayoz: Where did I say that alternative drivers weren't available?  I just described what the default behavior is.

Comment: The cookie just stores the session ID. Storing actual session DATA in a cookie would be a hideous security risk, e.g. keeping "superuser=0" on a client-side cookie would invite all sorts of "fun" things.

Comment: @Marc B, that's how codeigniter does it. http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html "The Session class stores session information for each user as serialized (and optionally encrypted) data in a cookie. It can also store the session data in a database table for added security, as this permits the session ID in the user's cookie to be matched against the stored session ID. By default only the cookie is saved."

Comment: Thank you @Rocket. So we should always use the database based type of session because the client can easily(?) change the user_id to root's user_id that is super terrible!

Comment: @smhnaji: CodeIgniter isn't insecure.  The session data might be editable by the client, but it validates it on each load.  If you change session data, the hashes won't match, and CodeIgniter will invalidate your session.  You can store session info in the db if you want, or you can use a library to enable CodeIgniter to use native PHP sessions.